# Database in emergency mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The database is in emergency mode and I have tried fixing it. But when I used the statement `DBCC CheckDB (TestDB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)` the log was not rebuilt. The log file is not present now. How can i bring the database online?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a backup and restore disaster recovery solution in place?  If so, restore the database from the most recent backup.

Assuming you don't have a backup, you may be able to use `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`, (see the [Microsoft Docs page for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql))

The general syntax for the command is:

```
CREATE DATABASE <db-name>
ON (NAME = '<logical-name>', FILENAME = '<source-to-mdf>')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

Be aware that if the mdf file is corrupt, you may lose everything.  Ensure you keep a copy of the mdf prior to attempting to attach it in this way.

An example of creating a database, setting it to "emergency" mode, detaching it, then re-attaching it without an existing log file:

```
CREATE DATABASE AttachTest
ON (NAME = 'sys', FILENAME = 'C:\temp\AttachTest.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME = 'log', FILENAME = 'C:\temp\AttachTest.ldf');

ALTER DATABASE AttachTest SET EMERGENCY;
```

Detach the database:

```
EXEC sys.sp_detach_db @dbname = 'AttachTest';
```

Delete the log file from the filesystem:

```
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell 'del "C:\temp\AttachTest.ldf"';
```

Attach the database, recreating the missing log file:

```
CREATE DATABASE AttachTest
ON (NAME = 'sys', FILENAME = 'C:\temp\AttachTest.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

You'll see this message:

> File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\temp\AttachTest.ldf" may be incorrect.
>   New log file 'C:\somepath\AttachTest_log.ldf' was created.

Cleanup the test database:

```
DROP DATABASE AttachTest;
```